# from six.moves import urllib ImportError: No module named six.moves

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have installed six but i got error below:

```
from six.moves import urllib
 ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

When executing

```
pip install six.moves
```

:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement six.moves (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for six.moves

i am using python 3.5.6

Comment: Note that `pip install six.moves` failed, as that is not a package. Try `pip install six`, after which `from six.moves import urllib` should work.

Comment: tried but still  show
 File "train.py", line 26, in <module>
    from six.moves import urllib


`import numpy as np
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.python.util import compat`

Comment: Hi, please see Tensorflow requirements https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows they need to work with compatibilities version of 1.x and 2.x but now it work with capability mode.

Comment: i have tensorflow 1.2. . It should work i guess.

Comment: A full traceback would help. If you're still having trouble, can you please edit the question to include the tracebact? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 26, in <module>
    from six.moves import urllib
ImportError: No module named six.moves

Answer (score 0):

`Tensorflow 1.x` is deprecated to use and no longer supported. This could be the reason for the above error.

Please try again by upgrading the tensorflow version to `TF 2.x` as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) which does not show any error while importing the above package.

You can use below code to install tensorflow

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow  #or
!pip install tensorflow==2.2  # can mention specific TF version to install
```

and then import six package libraries

`from six.moves import urllib`

**Note:** This **six** package get installed automatically while installing tensorflow:
[image]